# Starting a UWP CoreApplication in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm trying to spin up a `CoreApplication` in a C#.NET project.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After reading some of the MS docs, I've tried to port [the simplest example I could find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--setting-up-the-games-infrastructure), from C++ to C#.

```cs
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core;

class Program : IFrameworkViewSource , IFrameworkView {
    static void Main() {
        CoreApplication.Run(new Program());
    }

    public IFrameworkView CreateView() => this;

    public void Initialize(CoreApplicationView applicationView) {}
    public void Load(string entryPoint) {}

    public void Run() {
        CoreWindow window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
        window.Activate();

        CoreDispatcher dispatcher = window.Dispatcher;
        dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessUntilQuit);
    }

    public void SetWindow(CoreWindow window) {}
    public void Uninitialize() {}
}
```

However, the `CoreApplication.Run()` invocation always throws an exception:

- When `Main()` is annotated with `System.MTAThread`:

  ```
  System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
  ```
- When `Main()` is annotated with `System.STAThread`:

  ```
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'
  ```

None of the `IFrameworkViewSource`'s nor `IFrameworkView`'s methods are even called.

Comment: Do you need just C# UWP test app? Create in VS from scratch, why should you port any examples?

Comment: UWP are not standard C# Windows/Console applications. Use Visual Studio's *"Blank App (Univeral Windows)"* template.

Comment: The reason why I don't use the standard template is that I want to create my own UI framework (because I hate myself). So the C++ or C#/XAML templates don't do for me...

Comment: The [CompositionVisual sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CompositionVisual) shows how to write a frameworkless C# UWP app.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I just tried the code of the composition sample, but the `CoreApplication.Run()` call still throws the same exception. Their `.csproj` is different than mine; is there no summon a blank window from a _« good ol' »_ `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` project?

Comment: Did you build the composition sample itself, or did you just copy the code? Try building the sample from its own source. The problem may liesin how the project is packaged, rather than in the code itself.

Comment: In particular, you have to say `<OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>` because that's the type of app that supports CoreApplication.